# Getting Javascript Regular Expression from Page

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to grab a regular expression from an HTML element so that I can use it for evaluation later, but for some reason when I grab the RE from the DOM it's different than when I statically define it in my Javascript. Here is my testing code:

```
<p id="test">\\b31\\b</p>

<script>
var j = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
console.log(j);
var i = "\\b31\\b"
console.log(i);

</script>
```

The results of this are \\b31\\b for j and \b31\b for i. Why isn't j also \b31\b? More importantly, how do I fix this? Because my regular expression evaluation later won't work with j, and I need to be able to grab regular expressions from the page to evaluate later, but right now I can't unless I statically define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know exactly why this is happening, but you could just simply fix this with:

```
var j = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\");
```

see example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wjnm15gL/1/

Comment: This works. I'm curious as to why JS behaves differently with things it gets from the DOM, but this solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think the escaping happens when you declare a variable like 'var i', and when u use something like innerHTML to get a value like 'var j', it skipped that part somehow. Does anyone knows more about this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "fix" this. By design, the backslash in JS is used to escape special characters, such as newlines (\n). If you want to use a literal backslash, a double backslash has to be used.

If you want to use two backslashes, use four:

```
console.log('\\\\'); //returns \\
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings automatically escape special characters following a `\` character. Try this in your console to see:

```
console.log('It\'s a wonderful day');
//It's a wonderful day
```

That's why your `j` and `i` variables log differently to the console.